# Do you write a new sentence following quotation marks?

Tags: sentence, quotation-marks

In non-story related works, do you write a new sentence with a capital letter after you quote something? For example, let's say I write a sentence quoting a question: *The first question that is asked is "What is the meaning of life?"*

Then I want to write another sentence after it, such as: *The second question that is asked is "Why do we wonder about this?"*

Do I  put it after the first sentence that ends with a quote, like this:

*The first question that is asked is "What is the meaning of life?" The second question that is asked is "Why do we wonder about this?"*

Or do I start a new paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the instance you describe I would certainly write the quotations as separate sentences, as you illustrate. It would not be appropriate to start a new paragraph, as both sentences appertain to the same topic.

There are, however, circumstances in which one could easily continue the same sentence after a quotation. Consider the following:

John said "I insist you listen to me", and then sat down.

Mary said "no" whilst shaking her head.

Comment: Was he playing musical chairs?

Answer (score 1):

**Not necessarily.**

If the content of the quotation marks are a complete sentence, then you punctuate it like a sentence.

> The first question that is asked is "What is the meaning of life?"

But if it is not a sentence it is not punctuated ike one.

> The first question asked was to define "the meaning of life".